# bad tokenization in stanford postagger

Tags: nlp, tokenize, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm trying to use the Stanford POS tagger to tag some French text. To do that, I use the following command:

> cat file.txt | java -mx10000m -cp 'stanford-postagger.jar:'
>   edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger -model
>   models/french.tagger -sentenceDelimiter newline > output.txt

(There is one sentence per line.)

But I noticed that the tags were pretty bad, and that the real issue actually comes from the French tokenization itself. I think that the tokenization is done by an English tokenizer.

So I tried to only tokenize the text in French by doing this:

> cat file.txt | java -mx10000m -cp 'stanford-postagger.jar:'
>   edu.stanford.nlp.international.french.process.FrenchTokenizer
>   -sentenceDelimiter newline > tokenized.txt

And there the French tokens are good.

How can I tell the tagger to use the French model for tagging, but also the French tokenizer at the same time?

Comment: Are you restricted to command line use, or can you write a Java class for this?

Comment: I would prefer a command line use much more, or a command that can be called from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-tokenizerFactory` and `-tokenizerOptions` flags to control tokenization.  The "Tagging and Testing from the command line" section of the [javadoc for MaxentTagger](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html) has a complete list of available options.

I believe the following command will do what you want:

```
java -mx10000m -cp 'stanford-postagger.jar:' \
  edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger \
  -model models/french.tagger \
  -tokenizerFactory 'edu.stanford.nlp.international.french.process.FrenchTokenizer$FrenchTokenizerFactory' \
  -sentenceDelimiter newline
```

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error message : "Could not load tokenizer factory" followed by "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.stanford.nlp.international.french.process.FrenchTokenizer.newTokenizerFactory()"

Comment: Reading through the code, it looks like the docs are misleading. and that you need `-tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.international.french.process.FrenchTokenizer.FrenchTokenizerFactory`.

Comment: No, because now I get a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". Actually, just the fact of giving the default option "edu.stanford.nlp.
process.PTBTokenizer" generates an error...

Comment: OK, I edited the answer to use `'edu.stanford.nlp.international.french.process.FrenchTokenizer$FrenchTokenizerFactory'`, which worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it's working! How did you figure this out? Is this a sort of hack or the normal way to call it?

Comment: I looked at the code that creates the tokenizer to see how it actually works: https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/82b042daee8438efceadbd9e0a5d3af687266769/src/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.java#L552